# How to install Quasar without CLI, install Vue and Viteste and configure them?

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar, vitest

I need to create a project with Quasar without the CLI, and also with Vue and Vitest. Nowhere did I find how to install all these dependencies and configure to run a simple test. If anyone has already solved this problem and can help me, I would be grateful

I already tried to install Quasar manually, but when installing Vitest it generates several errors because it is not the Quasar version with the CLI.

Comment: The question is too unspecific, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . "I already tried to install Quasar manually" - what did you try? It's easier to fix the mistakes than writing it from scratch. It's intended to be used with CLI since it's a platform and not just a library

Comment: What is the output of error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.